# Embedding Razor within HTML within JS

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a dynamic table generated in JS which appends a button (and image) in one of the columns of the table:

```
var btn = $("<button/>", { class: "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle options_btn_custom", }).prepend('<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/Settings.png")" />');
```

The issue is the Razor image URL within the HTML is rendered incorrectly:

[image]

The URL of the image has to be relative (hence the Razor)...

I know its possible to embed Razor within JS directly, but is there a way for it to work also within embedded HTML, or is it too far a long shot?

Comment: Is the js in an external file? (razor is not parsed in external files)

Comment: oh really? far out, thats annoying... well I think I found a solution, which I'll post in a bit, but yeah I had to put the Razor in the view in the end...

Comment: You could just create a global var in the view - `var img = '@Url.Content(...);` and access from the external file(or if you handling an event of an element, add a `data-*` attribute)

Comment: yeah I did something similar, check out my answer. Too bad I couldn't keep it all within the external JS file though - that's what I was hoping for. Thanks for the help though, they were some cool pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix, didn't know I had to keep the Razor within the view... 
so in my view head I've got:

```
    <script>
    var baseurl = "@Url.Content("~/")";
    </script>
```

And then the JS within the external file:

```
 var btn = $("<button/>", { class: "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle options_btn_custom" }).prepend('<img src="' + baseurl + '/Content/img/Settings.png"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the value to a global js var and then you can use it in external js file

i.e

```
> var clientVar = null;
> 
> clientVar = '@Url.Content("~/Content/img/Settings.png")';
```

in external js file just use the clienVar. it should work

Answer (score 0):

The fact is Razor is not configured to process JS files by default. The easiest solution will be to inject your values in `cshtml` file in the `script` tag before your JS file reference:

```
<script>
    window.data = {
        settingsImageUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/img/Settings.png")';
    };
<script>
<script src="your-script.js" />
```

And then feel free to use `data.settingsImageUrl` in `your-script.js`:

```
var btn = $("<button/>", {
    class: "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle options_btn_custom", 
}).prepend('<img src=" + data.settingsImageUrl + " />');
```

### Alternative solution

Another possible solution is to build the script file with all the values required for your script on the fly. To make this you can setup a special route pointing to an action. In this action you will build your values as a string with JS object definition and return it as a `text/javascript` content. That will work fine with caching action filter. Then you just point to this route in a `script` tag injected before your target script.

Answer (score 0):

You could render a data attribute to a container holding the objects you will generate dynamically. Doing so prevents the usage of global javascript variables.

```
<div id="myAwesomeFunctionalityContainer" data-image-url="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/")"></div>
```

Then from your javascript file, read the data attribute "image-url"

```
(function () {
   "use strict";

   $(window).load(function () {
      var $container = $("#myAwesomeFunctionalityContainer");
      var imgPath = $container.data("image-url");
      var classDef = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle options_btn_custom";
      var btn = $("<button/>", {class: classDef}).prepend('<img src="' + imgPath + '/Setting.png" />');
   });
}());
```

The benefits are:

- no global variables which will cause headaches if you code libray grows.
- the payload is known to the container using data attributes. This works well for a limited amount of data. If you need more data/complex object from razor then you could render a model to a json string object. Afterwards convert the string object back to a json object using jquery.parseJSON